# Some Questions about the Lemma of Coherent Sheaf (Hartshorne' II.5.3a)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I am trying to understand the following Lemma ((a), Lemma 5.3, page 112 Robin Hartshorne), but some parts are causing me difficulties.

> **Lemma 5.3)** Let $X=\operatorname{Spec} A$ be an affine scheme, let $f\in A$, let $D(f) \subset X$ be the corresponding open set, and let $\mathcal{F}$ be a quasi-coherent sheaf on $X$.
>
> (a) If  $s \in \Gamma(X,\mathcal{F})$ is a global section of $\mathcal{F}$ whose restriction to $D(f)$ is $0$, then for some $n>0$, $f^{n}s=0$.

**(1)** Before doing the proof,  the author refers to some facts. First, he claims : $\mathcal{F}|_{D(g)}=(M \otimes_B A_{g})^{\sim}  $. I try to check his claim via the following facts.

> **Proposition 2.3)** Any moprhism of a locally ringed space from
> $\operatorname{Spec} B$ to $\operatorname{Spec} A $ is induced by a homomorphism of rings $A \to B$
>
> **Proposition 5.2)** Let A be a ring and $X=\operatorname{Spec} A$, Also let $A \to B$
> be a ring homomorphism, and let $f:\operatorname{Spec} B \to \operatorname{Spec} A $ be
> corresponding morphism of spectra. Then, for any $A$-module $M$,
> $f^{*}(\overset{\sim}{M})\cong (M \otimes_B A_{g})^{\sim}$

First, the author say an inculsion $D(g) \hookrightarrow V:=\operatorname{Spec} B $ corresponds to a ring homomorphism, $B \to A_{g}$. (proposition 2.3) Thus, I think that a locally ringed space(**really?**) $D(g)\overset{?}{=}\operatorname{Spec}~ A_{g} \to \operatorname{Spec} B $ is induced the before-mentioned ring homomorphism. And, then I myself induce the claim as :

$$ \mathcal{F}|_{D(g)} = \overset{\sim}{M} ~{\cong}~ \overset{\sim}{M} \otimes _{\mathcal{O}_X} \mathcal{O}_{X} = \overset{\sim}{M} \otimes _{i^{-1}{\mathcal{O}_X}} \mathcal{O}_{X}   = i^{*}(M) \overset{Prop ~5.2}{\cong} (M \otimes_B A_{g})^{\sim}$$

Is this the right proof? To begin with, I believe(!) to hold $D(g)=\operatorname{Spec} A_{g}$ because this is the right way in order to apply Proposition 2.3) But I am not sure whether this actually holds.

**(2)** *[Within the Textbook]* : ... *Hence, $\mathcal{F}|_{D(g)}=(M \otimes_B A_{g})^{\sim}  $. Thus we have shown that if $\mathcal{F}$ is quasicoherent on $X$, then $X$ can be covered by open sets of the form $D(g_{i})$ where for each $i$, $\mathcal{F}|_{D(g_{i})} \cong \overset{\sim}{M}_{i}$ for some module $M_i$ over the ring $A_{g_{i}}$. **Since X is quasicompact**, a finite number of these open sets will do.*

I do not understand why $X$ is quasi-compact. It is true that $X$ can be covered by open sets of the form $D(g_{i})$, but not covered by **finite** open sets.

**(3)** [Proof of the Proposition (a)] The author claims that $\mathcal{F}|_{D(fg_{i})}= (M_i)^{\sim}_{~f}$ for some module $M_i$ over the ring $A_{g_{i}}$ while verifying the proposition (a), But I am not sure why it holds. He refers that it holds because of the following proposition.

> **Propostion 5.1)**  For any $f \in A$, the $A_{f}$-module,
> $\overset{\sim}{M}(D(f))$ is isomorphic to the localization module
> $M_{f}$.

It is true that $ \mathcal{F}|_{D(g_{i})} = \overset{\sim}{M}_{i}$ because  $\mathcal{F}$ is a quasi-coherent sheaf. But I cannot reach to the way how to apply the above proposition.

Comment: Please use \operatorname{Spec} to format $\operatorname{Spec}$: it produces better spacing. I've made this change for you in your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of your issues are covered via definitions and exercises earlier in the text.

- Morphisms of schemes are exactly morphisms of locally ringed spaces. See the definition of a scheme on page 74.
- $D(g)\cong \operatorname{Spec} A_g$: this is exercise II.2.1.
- Your "proof" that $\mathcal{F}|_{D(g)}\cong (M\otimes_B A_g)^\sim$ is not a proof. Why should you be able to change the tensor product from being over $\mathcal{O}_X$ to being over $i^{-1}(\mathcal{O}_X)$? See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1886546/hartshorne-lemma-ii-5-3-proof?rq=1) for a previous version of this question with an answer.
- $X$ is quasi-compact as affine schemes are quasi-compact. This is exercise II.2.13.
- $\mathcal{F}|_{D(fg_i)} = (\mathcal{F}|_{D(g_i)})_{D(\widetilde{f})}$, where we take $\widetilde{f}$ to be the image of $f$ in the ring $A_{g_i}$. As $\mathcal{F}|_{D(g_i)}=\widetilde{M_i}$, we can apply proposition II.5.1 and we have our result.